# Does Google Drive API Allow us to download public file without authentication?

Tags: java, api, file, authentication, google-drive-api

I wonder that can I download public file from Google Drive using API without authentication? Probably I can, since any file can be downloaded if I see it without authentication. But Google Drive API Docs say the following;

[*Every request your application sends to the Drive API must include an authorization token.*](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth)

For instance, I can show the following public file and I'm trying to get it. Maybe, I dont even need to use Google Drive API. By the way, I'm using JAVA.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dXCaVmaqzROHNwdC1SQmdxejQ/view?usp=sharing

What can I do, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need authentication to read public files. The URL to the file download is as easy as this: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID>?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&alt=media`.

Answer (score 0):

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID>?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&alt=media` was giving me **CORS** error, so this is wat I did:

1. called  `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID>?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>` without `alt=media`
2. read the properties `downloadUrl` and `mimeType` on response
3. called `downloadUrl` with `responseType: arrayBuffer`
4. used `blob` to convert the `arrayBuffer` to a file that can be downloaded

The following code on angular do the job:

```js
async downloadZip(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const meta = await this.http.get(
      'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/<FILE_ID>?key=<API_KEY>'
      ).toPromise() as { downloadUrl: string, mimeType: string };
    const arrBuffer = await this.http.get(meta.downloadUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).toPromise();
    this.saveArrBuffer('testfile', meta.mimeType, arrBuffer);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

saveArrBuffer(fileName: string, type: string, arr: ArrayBuffer): void {
  const blob = new Blob([arr], { type });
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = fileName;
  link.click();
}
```

I struggle so much on that that I'm gladly to post.