# Google Drive API - File Download Issues with Service Account

Tags: python, django, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I'm setting up a Django-Heroku app to let users download videos (max 75MB).  I have tried this two ways now, and neither works how I want, so I'd like to know if I'm hitting some limitation or just not doing it properly.

**Environment**
I have a G Suite account with a service account with delegate-authority. The JSON key is in place, the API is enabled, the account is authorized with the proper scopes and I can download files.

**What I Want**
The user clicks on a link and the file downloads directly from Google Drive with no web app pass-through, sign-in, virus warning, etc.  It should be seamless -- click once and the file downloads.

```py
class GoogleDrive():

  service = 'drive'
  version = 'v3'
  permissions = ['read'] # Converts to "readonly" scope
  connection = connect() # Calls build() with appropriate scope / credentials
```

**Attempt 1 - Download GD file and return as HTTPResponse**

```py
# Get GD service
gd = GoogleDrive()

request = gd.connection.files().get_media(fileId='<SOME_ID>')
stream = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(stream, request)
done = False

# Get file in chunks
for retry in range(0, 5):
  while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()

# Build response
response = HttpResponse(stream.getvalue(), content_type=<SOME_CONTENT_TYPE>)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=sample.mp4' % # force download
response['Content-Length'] = <FILE_SIZE>

return response
```

From the user's view, this is what I want -- one click and the file downloads.  But I feel like the file is processed twice -- once to transfer it from Google Drive to the app server and a second time to send it to the user.  It works, but it takes some time and I feel it'll use up the web server's resources.

**Attempt 2 - Return a redirect URL to GD file download**

```py
# Get GD service
gd = GoogleDrive()

# Get file content URL
fileinfo = gd.connection.files().get(fileId=<SOME_ID>, fields='webContentLink').execute()
fileurl = fileinfo['webContentLink']

return redirect(fileurl)
```

This is also close to what I want, but if I'm not logged into the G Suite account, I get a 403 error on my cell phone or the Google Sign-in prompt on my laptop.

Is there a clean way to get what I want using the service account authorization?

Comment: From security standpoint it's better for the code that runs in the environment you cannot control (inside a browser on end user's cellphone or laptop) to have no credentials to access a cloud service with potentially sensitive data. The webserver you control should both have such credentials and decide if the end user is authorized. The latter can include either actually doing the authorization or accepting authorization done by other party that webserver trusts.

Comment: Thanks, I agree.  I authorize the end user on the webserver before sending the file.  My main question is if there is a way to bypass pulling the file into the webserver from Google Drive before pushing it to the user?  I just want to send the file directly from Google Drive to the user after authorization.

Comment: Hi ! Are the Google Drive files the user will be downloading **public** ? If so it would be as easy as using the public download link as shown in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59357839/12835757). Otherwise, let me know so that I can look for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The files are not public, but if there's a way to send the file to the user while obscuring the URL so they can't share it, then that would be fine too..

Comment: Hi ! Are your users within your own organization? Unfortunately, from [the documetation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) it does not seem to exist a way of downloading a file clicking on a link wihtout previous authorization however, I have found [this workaround](https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/03/20/download-files-without-authorization-from-google-drive/) that might help you. **Please let me know if this helps solves your issue to formalise it into an explained answer**.

Comment: Thank you my friend, this is pretty interesting.  I'm going to continue with my current implementation for now, but I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: Hi ! Have you tried the workaround ? Would you like any help in integrating this workaround with your existing piece of code? Thanks !

Comment: Thanks Mateo, I'm OK for now.  I appreciate it.